# Webpack resolve.alias vs resolve.root Performance difference?

Tags: webpack

I found this [comment](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/build-performance/99b3c2758589c35d62c3cdc03e312682de31dd6b) regarding the performance benefit of using `resolve.root` over `resolve.modulesDirectories`; however, I haven't see anything comparing `resolve.root` to `resolve.alias`. Is there a similar performance benefit to using one over the other?